# Disabled ports with UFW but outside scan still shows them as open?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw

UFW status verbose:

[image: This if my UFW status verbose]

And this is the result from an outside scan from pentest-tools.com

[image: And this is the reulst from an oudside scan from pentest-tools.com]

So, my understanding is that all ports BUT 22 and 443 should be closed, but some other still appear as open from the scan.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please copy and paste text from terminal and format it as code in your question. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1001101/edit) your question and more information about how your computer connects to the Internet? Is is through a router at home? Is it a router owned by someone else, such as your ISP, neighbor, school, workplace?

Comment: You ufw settings are allowing all traffic, so what is the problem ?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Panther It looks like the router has ports 21, 53, 80 and 3306 open. They may be NATed to other computers. Who knows?

Comment: This is a VPS im making this to.

The problem is t hat i want to secure this VPS as much as possible, and close everything but ssh and https

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was docker that bypasses the ufw:
[How to fix the Docker and UFW security flaw](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-fix-the-docker-and-ufw-security-flaw/)

or

[What is the best practice of docker + ufw under Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383845/what-is-the-best-practice-of-docker-ufw-under-ubuntu)

In my case adding `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file with `{"iptables":false}` worked (and altering `/etc/default/docker` not)